# Error PHP en wordpress al utilizar el comando use

Tags: php, wordpress

Añado en el archivo functions.php un código que utiliza la siguiente cadena

```
use Google\Spreadsheet\DefaultServiceRequest;
```

Y cuando guardo el fichero me da un error: Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'use' (T_USE)

Utilizo composer y el use tiene que ir dentro de la función ya que si lo saco fuero creo que es por eso que no me añade bien las cosas al sheet.

Answer (score 2):

Para poder utilizar **use** o en otras palabras "importar" o "incluir" una clase necesitas un namespace:

```
<?php

namespace foo;

use Google\Spreadsheet\DefaultServiceRequest;
```

El diseño que utiliza wordpress para el archivo functions.php no permite utilizar **use**, pues no es más que una compilación de funciones, sin un namespace ni una clase definida.

Puedes ver más información en la documentación de PHP: http://php.net/manual/es/language.namespaces.importing.php

Comment: Vale y el namespace para que sirve? donde lo he de definir dentro de la funcion o fuera?

Comment: Aquí tienes un enlace que lo puede explicar mejor que yo: http://php.net/manual/es/language.namespaces.rationale.php , en cuanto a tu problema la única forma sería utilizando un include() o similar, sin **namespaces** ni **use**.

Comment: Shaz y eso como o hago podrias poner un ejemplo?